# Appbar Title is not centered when back icon enabled react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am using [react native paper library](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/) for Appbar.

It is nice when I am showing Title and back and and menu is disabled.

Problem occurred when I enable back icon. **Text slightly moving to right**

[image: here title is okay]

In next image problem is showing - [image: Title moved slightly]

And the code I have done is,

```
const ContentTitle = ({ title, style }) => (
 <Appbar.Content
      title={<Text style={style}> {title} </Text>}
      style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
 />
`<Appbar.Header 
    style={{ backgroundColor: CONSTANTS.COLOR.BASE_COLOR }}>
     <Appbar.BackAction color="white" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.pop()} />
      <ContentTitle titleStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }} title={'History'} style={{ color: 'white', alignSelf: 'centered' }} />
</Appbar.Header>`);
```

What changes should I do to place title in center when back icon is enabled?

*NB: Basically I am getting this problem for android device.*

Answer (score 1):

You can set `appbar.BackAction` to `style={{ position: "absolute" }}`